# Remove transparent circles when using touchscreen (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen

We have a Windows 10 PC configured for an embedded application. There is no mouse or keyboard attached to the system and the user interacts with the software only via a touchscreen.

Whenever you touch the screen, a small transparent circle briefly appears where you clicked. After about 2-3s, the circle disappears. Similarly, if you click and hold a spot on the touchscreen, a small black square is briefly displayed on the screen.

I'd like to turn off these features and am assuming they are a combination of a few Windows 10 settings and/or hardware settings, but I cannot find them in Windows Settings or Device Manager.

How do I turn off these effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find touch feedback settings here:

- Windows Settings > Ease of Access
- Click `Other options > Visual options`
- Find the `Touch feedback` section
- Disable `Show visual feedback when I touch the screen`

Note! Windows 10 only displays `Touch feedback` settings if touch-enabled hardware was detected on power up. If you connect the PC to a standard, non-touch monitor offline...you will not see these settings and cannot configure them (except perhaps via the registry)! This is confusing and (in my view) a Windows 10 bug.